# How to bind to a source inside a ListBox different from the ItemsSource already specified

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, listbox

I have a ListBox inside a HubSection, whose Items are bound to a class "players" added to my DefaulViewModel via code behind.
First I simply put a TextBox bound to the property "PlayerName" of my class "players".
Now I would like to add a ComboBox with some items that are NOT part of the class players.

Is it possible ? I thought that definind an ItemsSource in the ComboBox would sort of override the ItemsSource of the ListBox, but nothing displays.

The DataContext of the whole page is defined like so:

```
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Then the HubSection is like so:

```
<HubSection x:Name="HubSec1">
        <DataTemplate>                    
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding players}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                       <StackPanel>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PlayerName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfElements}"/>                                                                                                                                                             
                        </StackPanel>
                     </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

If I define the ComboBox in the same way but outside the ListBox, it will display the string elements of "ListOfElements" properly.
But in this ListBox, the ComboBox is empty. So my guess is that having defined an ItemsSource for the ListBox, it is not possible to override it.

I have tried to define a DataTemplate but was not successful doing so, but it might be the good solution (and I did not proceed properly)

What am I missing ?

Edit :
The ComboBox items is an ObservableCollection. It is not part of the "players" class.
Here is how I added these elements to the DefaultViewModel

```
 DefaultViewModel.Add("players", players);
 DefaultViewModel.Add("MyItemsList", ListOfElements);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can walk up the visual tree and bind to an ancestors datacontext:

```
{Binding Path=PathToProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type typeOfAncestor}}}
```

EX:

```
{Binding Path=ListOfItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}
```

that should give you the datacontext that the listbox has, so assuming your ListOfItems exists in that data context.

Or you can name your control, and then bind to its datacontext by element name:

```
{Binding ElementName=mySourceElement,Path=ListOfItems}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have tried the "AncestorType" solution but I get an error in the IDE : "Member unknown 'AncestorType' on element 'RelativeSource'" (rough translation from french).

Comment: That should work, you could try this method too:
{Binding ElementName=ListBox1,Path=ListOfItems}

Comment: Any idea why I can't use the AncestorType option. When I type in "RelativeSource={RelativeSource" the IDE proposes only "Dispatcher" or "Mode", not AncestorType ... If I select Mode, there are 3 different properties : "none", "self", "TemplatedParent" ...

Comment: As mentioned below, I guess that method works in WPF, but not in windows phone, Sorry I assumed that we were in wpf. Perhaps the second method will work. Just name your outside most control, then bind to it by element name.

Comment: It is a universal application, I was working on the "windows part" of the app. However, I tried the second solution and it worked, thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

It can be a little bit tricky to create a good working binding in Windows Apps. A widely used work around is to use the `Tag` property.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding players}" Margin="0,184,0,0" Tag="{Binding Path=ListOfElements}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PlayerName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Tag, ElementName=ListBox1}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

A binding to an element wirh the specific name will work always. And the `ListOfElements` should be in the scope of the `ListBox` so you can use the `Tag` property as a proxy. If you need to bind more than one property, you can also use dummy XAML elements:

```
<Border Tag="{Binding ...}" Name="dummy1"/>
```

Comment: Don't use the Tag property. There is no need for it, and it is an extremely bad habit.

Comment: I get my binding correct to begin with. I have had to fix unimaginably horrendous code from developers that had a fondness for using the Tag property, and it's an old hack left over from the days of VB (where you had no other option).

Comment: @slugster I think you would change the model, right? It is possible but I do not understand why I have to change my data structure if it is much easier to do this completely in XAML. I also not understand what it has to do with VB from the Point of view of XAML.
 > I do not talk about the `Tag` property as a memory to access it from code behind and so on; it will only used as a redirecting route for the value

Comment: @slugster PS: I think about the problem from the view of Windows Apps. The `RelativeSource` is there not as good as in WPF. So @user1336827's first solution won't work there.

Comment: What would be the solution then ? Is the problem coming from how I organised my data ? Is my DefaultViewModel wrong ?