# DataContext ComboBox Binding inside of ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `ListBox` that displays a `List<Item> Items` with Item being a custom object. Foreach item I want the user to see a `ComboBox` with `List<string> Options` as the Source with the selected Item tying back to a property on a Item .  In the list box I have no trouble binding the individual Item properties but how do I reach back up into the DataContext to get my list of options?

View Model is being set as the page's DataContext

```
class ViewModel
{
      public ObservableCollection<string> Options { get; set; }
      public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <Grid Height="50" >
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> 
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <TextBlock x:Name="ItemProperty1TB" 
                     Text="{Binding Path=Property1, Mode=OneWay}"
                     Grid.Column="0" 
                 />
                 <ComboBox x:Name="OptionsCB" 
                     SelectedItem ="{Binding ChosenOptions, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Options}"          
                     Grid.Column="1" 
                     PlaceholderText="Option"
                 />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I tried to cut out as much extra code and get to a readable example.

[How to bind to a source inside a ListBox different from the ItemsSource already specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225600/how-to-bind-to-a-source-inside-a-listbox-different-from-the-itemssource-already) This uses AncestorType that does not exist?

[ComboBox inside Listbox.ItemTemplate Binding problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73130f47-05bd-4b5a-b8cc-acf598451c23/combobox-inside-listboxitemtemplate-binding-problem?forum=wpf) This binds to a static resource. Should I put my options into a static resource?

`ElementName` looks promising but my IDE only recommends Elements scoped to inside the ListBox... **DO NOT TRUST VISUAL STUDIO**

Am I just going about this all wrong?

Comment: ViewModel needs to have properties, not fields. Is that the actual code?

Comment: No that is not the actual code I will change that quickly

Comment: Try `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Options, ElementName=ItemsListBox}"`

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks It worked!!!!! When I firsted looked at that option the IDE recomended only elements inside that ListBox so I assumed it was Scoped locally. I should not have trusted Visual Studio

Comment: Ha! I was just about to tell you never to trust VS when you updated your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Options, ElementName=ItemsListBox}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RelativeSource property on Combobox binding object to find the parent. Something like this should work

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Options, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Replace UserControl with Page if you are using Page or Window for that matter.

Comment: That method appears to work in WPF, but not in windows phone.

Comment: OK I'm not sure about windows phone but you can use ElementName on your parent if that works in wp.